# Onepage - Go directly to payment

Tags: onepage-checkout, payment

For a specific order, I need to go directly to payment, with onepage system. 
For others orders, customer has to specify addresses and shipping method.

More details : A customer can create a quotation for marketplace order (processed with API). When quotation is validated, customer can order products with specific price. So I empty current cart to add these products, and customer is redirected to onepage. Addresses are specified in quotation so, customer will be redirected to payment page.

Any solution ?

Comment: What is your specific order? Based on SKU, customer, ...?

Comment: Based on a quotation.

Comment: OK, can please describe it a bit more detailed in your question?

Comment: I added more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably using [Virtual products](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-virtual.html) will help you.

> The process of creating a virtual product and a simple product is
>   nearly the same. However, because a virtual product is not shipped,
>   there is no Weight field or option to include a gift card.

Comment: No I need to send a real product with a real stock and custom price.

Comment: How would you know where to send that order?

Comment: Order will be sent to default customer address.